# To see, to watch, to meet - 看 vs 见 vs 看见

Tags: difference

I've seen 看 used on its own, 见 used on its own, and 看见 used together.

My understanding:

- 看 means "to see" or "to watch"， objects are typically inanimate (i.e.
  not people)
- 见 means "to see" or "to meet", objects are typically
  people

Is the above correct?

Why would you use 看见？ [This (Rocket Languages) site](http://xn--rcktbp9l7213b4vj.jp/your-community/chinese-grammar/difference-between-kan-and-jian) suggests it means "to catch a glimpse of".  Specifically, why use 看见　instead of just 见　？

It's [even a website!](http://www.kanjian.com/) where the object is 音了 -- as in, "see the music" ?

The Rocket Languages site also explains the [complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_grammar#Complement_of_result) form, 看不见　which suggests "can't" -- are there other examples

Comment: sometimes they are abbv form，我要去看一个病人，here，看=看望，探望，会见，拜访 ， it is same as 见 of 我要去见客户。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your understanding is correct for the basic use.
the difference between 看 and 看见，the latter usually means 'have seen/watched', which emphasizes the fact that sb saw sb/sth in the time before.

Comment: Thank for emphasis on "have seen/watched" -- before in time